# Finding code words given generator matrix and constructing syndrome table

Tags: coding-theory

Given a ternary (3,2) code with generator matrix
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Write down the Code words and thus construct table of coset leaders and their syndromes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a $(n,k)$ binary linear block code, the generator matrix $G$ specifies the codewords of the code $C$ by $C\equiv\{\bar{c}\in\mathbb{F}_3^n:\bar{c}=Gc,c\in\mathbb{F}_3^k\}$, consequently, the codewords of the presented code will be

- $c_1=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_2=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_2=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_3=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_4=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_4=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_5=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_5=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_6=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_6=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_7=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_7=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_8=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_8=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$
- $c_9=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\bar{c}_9=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

Now to get the syndrome table with the coset leaders, the parity check matrix of the code must be obtained, that is the matrix that $H^TG=0$, that in this case is

$H=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

Now the syndrome of a received vector is defined as $s = x^TH$, so for the case of this code, it will just be scalar value. The syndrome cosets then will be one for the vectors $x$ that have syndrome $0$, which by definition of the parity check matrix will be the set of codewords, while the other two cosests will be those of syndrome $1$ or $2$. The coset leader is defined as the words with smallest weight inside the coset, so

- $(s=0)$-Coset $\rightarrow$ coset leader $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$
- $(s=1)$-Coset $\rightarrow$ coset leader $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$
- $(s=2)$-Coset $\rightarrow$ coset leader $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

Note that there can be various coset leaders, as a coset may contain several words with the same weight, then you just chose one, as I have done here.

Note also that the notation that I have used for the derivtion of the things here is transposed compared with the standard notation of linear codes, where the generator matrix is defined as an $(k,n)$ matrix, and not as you did with the $(n,k)$ matrix. I did it this way basing on the input you gave for solving the problem. However, both formulations are equivalent one considering the words to be column vectors and the other as row vectors, so there is no conflict on solving the problem with the notation presented here.

Comment: What happens if the coset leaders have to be chosen with minimum weights?

Comment: What do you mean? I stated that the coset leaders must be the minimum weight words inside such coset. What I state later on is the fact that if there are multiple words inside the coset with such minimum weight, then you must choose one of them as the leader.

Comment: Oh ok...Never mind you already addressed that so! How do I decode the word 201 using the syndrome table?

Comment: Syndrome decoding is based on calculating sydrome of the received word and then using the coset leader for correcting such error. In that case the syndrome would be $s=x^TH=2$, so to correct the error, the coset leader of $s=2$ should be used to decode such as $x-s_{lead}=(2 0 1)- (1 0 0)=(2 0 1) + (2 0 0) = (1 0 1)$. Anyway, if the error that happened during the transmission is not the estimated error, then the decoding will not be succesfull.

Comment: Note that the coset leader is set as the minimum weight word because it is related with the most likely error to occur during channel transmission with that syndrome, implying a higher succes rate in the correction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I had a binary code with generator matrix $$
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\                                                                                                             
 0 & 1 \\                                                                                                                                   
1 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$    Would the code words then be 0000,0111,1001,1110 and then the H for obtaining syndrome would be 0110? Just stuck on how to get syndromes once H is obtained

Comment: No, note that the parity check matrix is defined as a $(n-k)\times n$ matrix, so for the code you just presented it should be a $2\times 4$ matrix. The syndromes will again be defined as $s=x^tH$, with $x$ being any possible word in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Comment: So what would the parity check matrix be?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$